# Curious case of segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I faced a weird case of segfault in a c++ program. I'm able to reproduce it in a small code, but don't understand why is it happening. Here is the code:

**a.hpp**:

```
#pragma once
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include "b.hpp"

class A
{
    public:
        explicit A ();    
    private:
        std::string str1_;
        B b_;
        std::string str2_;
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr< A > A_ptr;
```

**a.cpp**

```
#include "a.hpp"
A::A () {}
```

**b.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class B
{   
    public:
        B ();
    private:
        std::string str1_;
};
```

**b.cpp**

```
#include "b.hpp"    
B::B () {}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "a.hpp"

int main ()
{
    A_ptr a( new A() );
}
```

**Output of make**:

```
% make
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -fno-inline -O0   -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -fno-inline -O0   -c -o a.o a.cpp
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -fno-inline -O0   -c -o b.o b.cpp
g++  -o main main.o a.o b.o 
dsymutil main
```

Now this runs fine. I remove `B b_` (declaration of `b_`) from `a.hpp`, save `a.cpp` (to trigger a build) and run `make` again:

```
% make
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -fno-inline -O0   -c -o a.o a.cpp
g++  -o main main.o a.o b.o 
dsymutil main
```

And now program segfaults with:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff97f106e5 in std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose ()
#1  0x00007fff97f10740 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string ()
#2  0x0000000100001091 in A::~A (this=0x1001008b0) at a.hpp:8
#3  0x00000001000011da in boost::checked_delete<A> (x=0x1001008b0) at checked_delete.hpp:34
#4  0x0000000100001026 in boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<A>::dispose (this=0x1001008d0) at sp_counted_impl.hpp:78
#5  0x0000000100000d9a in boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release (this=0x1001008d0) at sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:145
#6  0x0000000100000dd4 in boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count (this=0x7fff5fbff568) at shared_count.hpp:305
#7  0x0000000100000f2b in boost::shared_ptr<A>::~shared_ptr (this=0x7fff5fbff560) at shared_ptr.hpp:159
#8  0x0000000100000aac in main () at main.cpp:5
```

And if I `make clean` and `make`, then program runs without segfault. Please help me understand why program segfaults if a member from class is removed and project is built without clean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On your second run of `make`:

```
% make
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -fno-inline -O0   -c -o a.o a.cpp
g++  -o main main.o a.o b.o 
dsymutil main
```

you are recompiling just `a.cpp`.
Then linking to the rest of object files produced in the previous run of make. This will make `main.cpp` use the older definition of `class A` (contained in `a.h`), while the new object file for `class A` (`a.o`) will use the newer definition, hence the crash.

(Concretely, new `class A` has different size, so the memory it needs to be reserved on the stack in `main()` is different and the disposition of its member variables is also different).

This is clearly a problem of faulty dependencies in your `Makefile`.

When you run `make clean/make`, all the files will use the same, correct definition for `class A` and everything will work out correctly.